# rails: render partial with jquery foreach

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, parameters, partial

i would like to append in my view several times a partial with different params.
i have a search form that return a projects json with ajax.
now i would like to call get jquery fonction with a project and show it in the view.

```
$.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url:"mycontroller/projects",
  //dataType:"json",
  data: { project: project, user: user,periode: periode },
  success:function(result) {
      if(result.length == 0 ) {
        $("#notice").show().fadeOut(5000)
      } else {
        $.each(result, function(i, item) {
          $("#res").append(**mypartial**)
      });
    } 
  }
});
```

and the in my partial a will do something like:

```
Poject : %= preject.name %
users:
% project.users.each do |user| %
- %= user.name %
%end%
```

there's a way to do this please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can include that AJAX script within `<script></script>` tag at the bottom of the `.html.erb` template which tiggers this AJAX call.

For example: If your view file making that AJAX call is `index.html.erb`

```
<!– ... other tags in index.html.erb –>

<script>
  $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"mycontroller/projects",
    //dataType:"json",
    data: { project: project, user: user,periode: periode },
    success:function(result) {
        if(result.length == 0 ) {
          $("#notice").show().fadeOut(5000)
        } else {
          $.each(result, function(i, item) {
            $("#res").append("<%= render partial: 'path_to_partial' %>")
        });
      } 
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks sa77 for your reply. But how can I send params project to the partial ?

Comment: you can pass it as locals, just like you do on your regular view files

Comment: that's what i did:
<pre>
$("#res").append("<%= render partial: 'stat', locals: {test: result} %>")
</pre>

but in the view i had <%= render partial: 'stat', locals: {test: result} %> writen !

Comment: you're trying to pass a js variable into ruby partial, partials are computed in your app server and plain HTML is sent as a response. it's okay if your partial is just plain HTML with no ruby stuff on it. However, you can compute a HTML partial on your action response `format.html { render partial: 'partial', locals: { test: result} }` on your controller and send that genrated HTML to your ajax response and on ajax success, just do `$('#res').html(result);`, where the result you get from AJAX response is HTML content with dynamic data filled through the locals you pass into it.